# Live feed error log?

Tags: c#

How would one go about creating a progress log and erorr log that constantly displays to the user?
I have an external text files where the log info is kept and stored. However, If i wanted to give a live feed to the user of what is going on in the program, and for them to see errors constnatly as the program goes, how would one do that? I know how to display the text files in a rich text box, however to have a live feed and to be constantly updating is the part where I am confused on...
Any help and ideas would be great.

Comment: Can you just update the text in your rich text box every time your program writes an error log to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). You can create your custom log appender which you could use to update your view.